# Request callback does not get called until end

Tags: node.js

Why is Request callback not called at all in this example?
Output of this would be:

```
here
now here
```

"did it!" or any log commands in callback does not get called.

```
var request = require('request');

d=0;
console.log("here");
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
  d=1;
});
console.log("now here");
while(d==0){}
console.log("did it!");
```

If I remove "while(d==0){}". Then it gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you actually stuck in `while(d==0){}` because you are making async code with sync

The async code fires in the event loop so the flow of the application going with the sync code which will fire the `while` loop and start iterate.

Comment: But isn't request's callback called asyncronously? it is supposed to finish itself and then call its callback? Where am I wrong?

Comment: yes , but before it came back to the main thread the while loop fires and always run.

Answer (score 0):

Your process is stuck in an endless loop.

Replace your d=1 in the callback with console.log("did it!"), and get rid of the while loop.

(ie. everything you want to run after the response is returned, you should put inside the callback function)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your while is starving the main thread, the callback passed to request will never be executed since the main flow will never finish execute, I'd suggest you to study a little bit of the [event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) of node.js.

This while loop starves the event loop by running
infinitely, greedily checking and rechecking a value that is never given a chance
to change, as the event loop is never given a chance to schedule your request callback
for execution.